# Peek method in my JavaScript implementation of a stack is undefined

Tags: javascript, data-structures, stack

I have implemented a version of the Stack data structure in JS.

Here is my code

```
class Stack {
    constructor() {
        this.stack = [];
    };

    push(item) {
        return this.stack.push(item);
    };

    pop() {
        return this.stack.pop();
    };

    peek() {
        return this.stack[this.length - 1];
    };

    isEmpty() {
        return this.length === 0;
    };

    getLength() {
        return this.stack.length;
    };
}
```

Everything here works well, except for the peek method. It returns undefined. I'm not sure why.

This is how I'm using it.

```
const stack = new Stack();
console.log(` The stack contains : ${stack.getLength()} items`);
stack.push(1);
stack.push(2);
console.log(`The stack contains : ${stack.getLength()} items`);
console.log(stack.peek());
```

This is the output

```
The stack contains : 0 items
The stack contains : 2 items
undefined
```

Comment: `this.stack.length`, not `this.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `this.stack.length` instead of `this.length`:

```js
peek() {
    return this.stack[this.stack.length - 1]; 
};
```

Same for all other references to `this.length`